Commands in the same line with sshpass not recognized
I was running a script normally. But suddenly, all the commands in the same line with sshpass started being not recognized. For instance:
sshpass -p "$password" rsync -a -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p $port" "$username@$hostname:${src_dir}${dir}/" "${dest_dir}${dir}/"

dirs=$(sshpass -p "$password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p "$port" "$username@$hostname" "ls -lt --time-style=long-iso '$src_dir' | grep '^d' | head -n 3 | awk '{print $8}'")

These commands run (head,ls and the rest) successfully in other parts of the script. sshpass is installed:
atmos_username@atmosserver:~$ which sshpass
/usr/bin/sshpass

bash: grep: command not found bash: head: command not found bash: awk: command not found bash: ls: command not found rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver] rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(231) [Receiver=3.2.7] Copying /mnt/ops/lap_ops/data/KASTOM_OUT/Tiff_files/20240529 to /home/sftp/life-sirius/uploads/Tiff_files/ bash: rsync: command not found

My OS is:
atmos_username@atmosserver:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Output of declare -p PROMPT_COMMAND:
atmos_username@atmosserver:~$ declare -p PROMPT_COMMAND
-bash: declare: PROMPT_COMMAND: not found

atmos_username@atmosserver:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Output:
atmos_username@atmosserver:~$ . "/home/atmos_username/2024/ditsiaou_life-sirius/ubuntu_forum.sh"
Attempting SSH connection...
SSH Connection successful.
-bash: /mnt/ops/lap_ops/data/KASTOM_OUT/Tiff_files/: No such file or directory
trial=
bash: head: command not found
bash: awk: command not found
bash: grep: command not found
bash: ls: command not found
dirs= $(dirs)
Copy operation completed.
Delete of 3 days old
Directory /home/sftp/life-sirius/uploads/Tiff_files/20240528/ does not exist.
End of file
20240529  20240530  20240531


You already posted your question here - please decide which site you want to ask on and delete the other

Since I have to choose a site, which one do you think is more appropriate? I think Unix and Linux. Thanks.

I suspect you accidentally set PROMPT_COMMAND to a malformed command that tries to execute bash, head, awk etc in ~/.bashrc or somewhere else, what's the output of declare -p PROMPT_COMMAND?

@kos atmos_username@atmosserver:~$ declare -p PROMPT_COMMAND
-bash: declare: PROMPT_COMMAND: not found

@kos the strange is that I perform head and ls in the same script (in different line from sshpass) and they performed as expected.

Please format commands and outputs as explained in Markdown help, and also please add any important information (or any information containing code / output for that matter) to the question itself, so that it can be read by others and so that it's easy enough to read / whitespace won't get mangled during the copy-paste process

Please review my edit and reformat the code / output you posted yourself, I think I've done a bad job at it (and I also didn't understand the problem correctly)

@kos here is the script https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cZ8qygoqqAWh7O-7O3uuZypYvqXK8tVY/view?usp=sharing

So far as I can see, the whole pipeline is being passed to the remote host - so you will need to look at the $username user's login bash shell on $hostname - most likely the PATH environment variable is set incorrectly

@steeldriver i have add the results of
atmos_username@atmosserver:~$ echo $PATH
in the end of the question.
In the beginning of the file it is printed that the ssh connection is successful. I dont know why but the problem is in commands being in the same line with sshpass.

But is that from the local shell or the remote shell? You need something more like sshpass -p "$password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p "$port" "$username@$hostname" 'echo "$PATH"'

The code is in the local shell. The credentials are from the remote (username,password). But, until today morning there was no problem.
And although it connects it doesn't recognize the commands. I modify the answer to see the output.

@steeldriver I mean the question, in the end of my question.

I don't know what's going on, as steeldriver said the errors appear to be coming from the remote shell, not from the local shell, however the output you posted right after which sshpass, which appears to be running on the local shell, also shows some errors right after. Please review and edit your question making sure commands and outputs are correctly formatted and explaining where you're running each command exactly, if you get errors from sshpass only in the script etc. But I second what steeldriver said, the problem seems to be on the remote host.

The problem was in the remote pc. In the bashrc file of the remote pc :
echo 'export PATH=/mnt/lap_c/home/ditsiaou/2023/.../...//sshpass/bin:/mnt/lap_c/home/ditsiaou/2023/.../.../' >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc

echo 'export PATH=/mnt/lap_c/home/ditsiaou/2023/.../...//sshpass/bin:/home/d/ditsiaou' >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc

Thanks for the help.
